# Needs all the divs to appear in same row

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with div items section1, section2, section3 as i need them to be set in a row. Section3 seems to be below the other two. Do you know why it is so ? I need all of them to be in the same line.

[image: issue]

```
div.bodySection
{
padding:5px;
background-color:lime; 
margin-left:10px;
display:inline-block;
}

<div id="section">

<div id="section1" class="bodySection">
<h1><London></h1>
<p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="section2" class="bodySection">
<h2><London></h2>
<p1>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="section3" class="bodySection">
<h3><London></h3>
<p1>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: the tags `<london>` `<p1>` and `<p2>` do not exist and you can't simply create a new tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use CSS flexboxes: https://jsfiddle.net/p22u9h1L/

Adding another CSS block for your `section div` fixes your alignment issue:

```
div#section
{
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer - you would have thought that it would allign automatically in a row without your suggestion...do you know why?

Comment: It's possible the size of the text and the assigned padding + margin might have been too large for the container you placed the sections in, causing one of them to pop down. Flexboxes allow for the containers to fit and dynamically resize with the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

See the possible solution following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   ul#row li  {display:inline;}
   .div-inline {display:inline-block;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="row">
    <li>
       <div class="div-inline">
         <h1><London></h1>
         <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div class="div-inline">
         <h2><London></h2>
         <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div class="div-inline">
         <h3><London></h3>
         <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help.